# Search in favor of tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

I retagged a question to make it easier to find, but turned out, tags show in the result set but aren't more important than the text (free text search in question title, body, answers...).

Went to the Help Center and found out that one can search in certain tags only using:

`[python] [curves] [import]`

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+curves+import

This is the result I wanted, but it's awkward to type and no regular user will know the `[tag]` syntax.

Is there any trick, like a hidden search form to search in favor of tags somewhere? Or a way to select multiple tags and get all matching answers which contain at least these tags? (Tags page shows related tags only, and one can't remove tags once combined)

Comment: I would think that _this_ is the feature. I would also say that you and I are average users, if one wants to utilize the site efficiently, poke around the help pages for a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah I guess, but I wonder why there is no neat interactive way to create these queries without brackets (or even keyboard)... Anyway, probably more appropriate to report this as feature request to the SE staff. Thanks iKlsR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are on any tag page (example [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling)) you will see that the search box has already been populated with the correct syntax to search in just that tag.
This makes it much easier for a "regular user" to learn about the powers of the search box.

PS if you are on the [search page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search) and you click the "*Advanced Search Tips*" you will see many of the most common features, but for a full list refer to [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/searching).